# Rails form_with: is local:true the same as remote:false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

In other words, are these two clauses just mirror images of each other? The documentation for form_with isn't clear on this.

Answer (score 9):

> local:true the same as remote:false?

If you mean that `remote: false` of `form_for` and `local: true` of `form_with` are same, then yes, they both are same!. But if mean the `remote: false` and `local: true` of `form_with` are same, then IDK. Infact there **isn't any option** called `remote` available in `form_with`.

The below are the details from [`form_with`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with) and [`form_for`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)

> :local - By default form submits are remote and unobstrusive XHRs.
>   Disable remote submits with local: true.

and

> :remote - If set to true, will allow the Unobtrusive JavaScript
>   drivers to control the submit behavior. By default this behavior is an
>   ajax submit.